# Javascript variable getting null despite initialized

Tags: javascript

Here a very simple code(just getting started out):

```
       <head>

       </head>
       <title>Title here</title>
       <script src="index.js"></script>
       <body>
           <h1>People counter</h1>
           <h2 id="count-element">0</h2>
           <button id="increment-button" onclick="increment()">Increment</button>
       </body>
   </html>
```

Here is the index.js

```
let countElement = document.getElementById("count-element")
let count = 0

console.log(count)
function increment(){
    
    count =count +1
        countElement.innerText = count
    
}
```

The problem is:
[On clicking the button it fails:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyaYz.png)

*I am using xampp on win 10(64)
Even tried wampserver but both failed
Tested on chrome and edge browsers
**BUT**
on codepen.io it works*

Comment: If it wasn't initialized it would be `undefined`, so you are initializing it to `null`.

Comment: Writing from a mobile but could you change your two let statements to var statements?

Comment: @AydinK. — Whatever for? `var` should be avoided unless you need to support ancient browsers.

Comment: @quentin: I was just guessing that the issue might be due to variable scoping problems, but not 100% sure

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answers but i managed to solve my problem: it was in the html file: the script tag was initiated in the  head and not in the body tag. I put it in the body and the problem gone.